# alias method in sample()

Tags: r

In R, when applying sample(), if replace is true, Walker's alias method is used when there are more than **250** reasonably probable values. Is there a way to make sample() always use alias method? Thanks!

Comment: No, there isn't, but @DirkEddelbuettel should be along shortly and he will show you how to do it with Rcpp.

Comment: Here is the source of the function, see `do_sample`, http://svn.r-project.org/R/trunk/src/main/random.c

Comment: There are also a few implementations floating around using python, if you're comfortable with that language.

Answer (score 1):

One option would be to replicate both your `x` and `prob` vectors enough times that the resultant vectors are longer than 250 elements. It's a hack, sure, but a fun one!

```
sampleWalker <- function(x, size, prob) {
    nx <- length(x)
    nrep <- 251 %/% nx + 1
    sample(x = rep(x, nrep), size = size, replace = TRUE, prob = rep(prob, nrep))
}

sampleWalker(1:3, 10, prob = 1:3)
#  [1] 3 1 2 3 3 2 2 1 2 3
# Warning message:
# In sample.int(length(x), size, replace, prob) :
#   Walker's alias method used: results are different from R < 2.2.0
```